# Expected Improvement formula for Bayesian Optimisation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

The expected improvement on how to choose a next point $x$ for evaluation is to choose the point such that $$arg\,max_{x}E[f(x) - f^{max}]$$

where $f(x)$ denotes the gaussian process posterior distribution at location $x$ and $f^{max}$ denotes the current maximal point from the gaussian process.

Since $f(x)$ is random and $f^{max}$ is fixed, the above equation can be reduced to
$$
\begin{aligned}
EI(x) &= arg\,max_xE[f(x)] - f^{max}\\
&= arg\,max_x \mu(x) - f^{max}
\end{aligned}$$

$\mu(x)$ is the posterior mean of the gausisan process which can be analytically derived. However, in this other [stack exchange post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/426782/intuitive-understanding-of-expected-improvement-for-gaussian-process), the EI is developed somewhat more complexly and I do not really understand the derivation behind it.

Is my understanding of EI that I have mentioned above wrong ? or Am i missing something

Comment: i realised my error. The expectation is taken with respect to the $$max(f(x) - f^*, 0)$$ which takes into account the fact that if a sample of $x$ from $f(x)$ is lower than the current optimum, than the EI for that sample is 0 rather than negative

Answer (score 2):

As you have already addressed in your comment, the EI acquisition function is

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
a_\text{EI}(\mathbf{x}) &=& \mathbb{E}[{\max\left(y, f(\mathbf{x}_\text{best})\right) - f(\mathbf{x}_\text{best})}] \\
&=& \mathbb{E}[{\max(y - f(\mathbf{x}_\text{best}), 0}] \\
&=& \mathbb{E}[(y - f(\mathbf{x}_\text{best})^+] \\
&=&  \sigma(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (\gamma(\mathbf{x}) \Phi(\gamma(\mathbf{x})) + \phi(\gamma(\mathbf{x})),
\end{array}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{\mu(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x}_{\text{best}})}{\sigma(\mathbf{x})},$ $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the PDF and CDF of [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution), respectively.